# How to properly deploy a Spring Boot Web App on Heroku?

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot Web application to HEROKU and I am getting the following error:

***> -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

> -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app  !     No default language could be detected for this app.             HINT: This occurs
> when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application
> automatically.            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
> !     Push failed***

I tried setting the build back to heroku/java manually only to also get an error.
The app is built in java so I don't understand what is happening exactly. This is my first time deploying an app online. Any help or guidance will be greatly appriciated

Comment: Are you using Maven? Heroku recognises the buildpack if you have a pom.xml in the root of your project

Comment: Yes, I am using Maven with Spring Boot. I will double-check that the POM.xml file is at the root of the git project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beppe C. gave me the solution. My pom.xml file was not at the root. I restructured my repo and I got past that error but faced another one.